# Automated application provisioning and file locking

Tags: iis-7.5, web-farm-framework

We have WFF 2.5 installed, and have used it to successfully configure a farm and provision a secondary server in our test environment.

Our environment (controller, primary, secondary servers) is Windows 2008 Server Web Edition R2, running IIS 7.5, with WFF 2.5 installed.

We have ongoing issues with a .tmp file in an app pools related directory being locked. Process Monitor indicates that it is the worker process (w3wp.exe) locking the file.

The exact error message is Failed to run operation "ProvisionApplications". Failed to run method "Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod" on server "abc". Exception in response stream. An error was encountered when processing operation "Delete File" on "ABC85DA.tmp". The error code was 0x80070020. The process cannot access "C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\ABC85DA.tmp" because it is being used by another process

If I shut down the Windows Process Activation Service which AFAIK hosts the worker process, the error is disappears.

Obviously, however , to bring the server online, we need to start the service, and as soon as we do, the automated provisioning step fails, and WFF marks the server as unhealthy, and takes it out of the farm.

I have tried to turn Application Provisioning off by unchecking "Enable Application Provisioning" under the Application Provisioning Module, but the operation still seems to fire every 30 seconds.

So - two problems really:

1. How to solve the file locking issue on the App pool temp file.
2. How to turn off automated application provisioning operation on
   secondary servers? (this is really a second prize workaround in case
   there is no solution to problem 1)

   TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the ARR server caused the server to stop attempting to repeatedly provision the secondary servers (in other words applied the "Enable Application Provisioning" option, which I had turned off)

Otherwise, I think the locking issue would still occur. This may not be an issue, since you can turn off the Windows Process Activations Service while initially provisioning the service, and during any subsequent application provisioning intended to synch the servers.

Automated provisioning on a schedule will still be an issue, I suspect.